# .htaccess allow file just if string is added at end

Tags: .htaccess

i have some links

```
example.com/1.mp4
example.com/2.mp4
```

is there a way to block accessing directly to those files but allow just if u add this

example.com/1.mp4?token=12345

so all mp4 files can be access only if u add **?token=12345** at end

so without it

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^token=12345
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

i tried this but is not working, so i want those mp4 to be played on vlc or any other player just if ?token=12345 is presend otherwise redirect to any other video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you had should work. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=token=12345
RewriteRule \.mp4$ - [F,L]
```

That will return forbidden on `.mp4` files unless `token=12345` is present. As for redirecting to a video, you could do that with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=token=12345
RewriteRule \.mp4$ /video [R=301,L]
```

Replacing `/video` with the path to the video. Make sure it's not `.mp4` or you'll get a loop.

Let me know any problems.