# .htaccess rule acting like a password

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a bunch of .mp4 file in a directory and I'm trying to make .htaccess rule to :

If I try to access them directly like : http://example.com/movies/file1.mp4 it redirect me to http://example.com/movies/default.mp4

I want to request user to access like this : http://example.com/movies/file1.mp4?Pass  if ?Pass is good according to .htaccess let user see the .mp4 if not redirect to http://example.com/movies/default.mp4

I don't get how to archive this, I never using .htaccess except to make login:user style access, no redirect.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking for. please clarify your question.

Comment: Is it more clear? I want to request pass at the end of url/files, pass set in .htaccess

Comment: I'm able to redirect all files to default file, but not the ?Pass thing. Nor directory itself /movie should redirect to default.mp4 aswell

Comment: This seems like good resource but I don't get it for my current wanted process : http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Is ?pass a randon query perameter or fixed perm?

Comment: fixed, I would set in in .htaccess it self

Comment: so allfile need to have ?DesiredPass at the end, not providing or going to /movie directory where video is redirect to default.mp4

Comment: I already answered this for you twice under other usernames, which you have deleted (wasting my work on that). As I explained to you when looking closely at your setup, it is your other rules causing the problem and not the solution I gave you. Set up logging and find out exactly what is going on with the rewrites I already gave you. Stop wasting people's time asking again in a slightly different way.

Comment: Sorry you didn't delete both questions, please refer to [the answer I already gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969177/make-htaccess-rules-just-for-some-folders/41970077?noredirect=1#comment71119002_41970077).

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, [the other post answering this is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947996/htaccess-allow-file-just-if-string-is-added-at-end).